# Include Page Number in Abstract

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, abstract

I'm trying to include a page number on my abstract page.  Here is how I have it set up so far (cutting out some extra things):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Name}
\maketitle

\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{abstract}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Lorem Ipsum etc, etc.
\end{abstract}
```

This generates a document without page numbers on either the title or the abstract.  I don't need to put one on the title, but is there a way I can force it to insert a page number for the abstract?

Thanks!

Edit for clarification: I needed to use roman numbering for all the intro sections (abstract, index, etc), then switch to arabic for the rest of the paper.  I ended up with the following:

```
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: I answered your question. Anyhow, you should clarify what *sort* of page numbering you want to achieve (e.g. `roman` for the whole document).

Comment: I edited the post for clarification.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `\thispagestyle{plain}` immediately after starting your `abstract` environment. (In the `report` class, at the begin of the `abstract` environment, `\titlepage` is called internally by default, which sets `\thispagestyle{empty}`.)

EDIT: If you want to switch to arabic page numbering for the rest of your paper, consider to use the `book` class instead of `report` and to use its `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands. You may emulate the behaviour of `report` with `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`. (Note that the `book` class doesn't provide an `abstract` environment; however, an unnumbered frontmatter chapter is quite suited for an abstract of a longer work.)

Comment: +1 for explaining not only what would work, but also why.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works with

- abstracts that start after a number of pages,
- abstracts which are followed by a number of pages, and
- multi-page abstracts.

```
\newcounter{abstractpage}
\setcounter{abstractpage}{\value{page}}

\begin{abstract}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \setcounter{page}{\value{abstractpage}}

  Lorem ipsum.

  \setcounter{abstractpage}{\value{page}}
\end{abstract}

\setcounter{page}{\value{abstractpage}}
\stepcounter{page}
```