# Roman numbers in abstract of report class

Tags: page-numbering, abstract, report, roman-numerals

I want to add roman page numbering to all the pages up to the end of the table of contents, apart from the title page. So I did the following, which works, apart from the fact that the abstract does not have any page number.

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\include{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

The `abstract.tex` file contains `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}`.

So I tried to follow the solution to the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16345/include-page-number-in-abstract) which seems to be asking the exact same question.

And in my abstract tex file I put:

```
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain} 

My abstract...

\end{abstract}
```

This does add page 'i' to the Abstract page. However, the problem is that subsequent pages in the roman numbering part, such as the table of contents are also getting page 'i' again (that is before changing to arabic numbering).

So essentially I am getting:

Abstract - Page i,
TOC - Page i

While I want

Abstract - Page i,
TOC - Page ii

Why is the counter getting reset to 1 (before changing to arabic numbering) and not continuing from where it was in the abstract?

Comment: `\pagenumbering{arabic}` does always reset the page counter to `1`

Comment: The resetting is happening before that. The table of contents is also getting 'i' which is before changing to arabic. Even when I tried adding an acknowledgements page after the abstract, it got 'i' instead of following the next roman page number. I can't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pagenumbering` - changes should be done after a `\clearpage` (unless it's the first change right after the start)

`\pagenumbering` always resets the page counter to `1`, see the definition

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname
   \c@page}}
```

`\global\c@page \@ne` is basically `Plain TeX` for `\setcounter{page}{1}`

Now the real culprit for `report` is that it sets `titlepage` option, i.e. `abstract` uses the `titlepage` environment internally, which is defined to reset the page number at the end.
Some code from `latex.ltx`

```
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
       \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi

\if@compatibility
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\z@
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    }
\else
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
     \if@twoside\else
        \setcounter{page}\@ne
     \fi
    }
\fi
```

**Here the real code**

The whole issue can be cured if `titlepage` is redefined to take care for the special needs of the O.P. by setting `\@abstractmode` to true and setting the pagestyle and stepping the page counter accordingly, but do no reset of the page counter at the end of the `titlepage` environment.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@abstractmode

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
{
  \if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
  \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \if@abstractmode
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \stepcounter{page}%
  \else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
}%
{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
  \if@twoside\else
  \if@abstractmode
  \else
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
  \fi
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{%
  \@abstractmodetrue%
}


\makeatother



\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{First}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit what the `blindtext` package is and what the command does? thanks.

Comment: @jbx: `\blindtext` is a famous package that adds dummy text, just to fill up the content

Comment: @jbx It's basically a Lorem Ipsum. :)

Comment: Yes just realised that, after posting my comment :). How is your solution different to what I pasted in my question though? I am getting page number 'i' before changing to arabic, within the roman part. So Table Of Contents is getting page 'i'. It is before the arabic part, so ignore the arabic part, that is working fine. I want Abstract - (i), TOC (ii) ... etc. then Chapter 1 is Page 1 (which is working perfect). But I am getting Abstract - (i), TOC (i) <--- why?!

Comment: @jbx -- I misunderstood. I thought up to, not up to the end of ToC

Comment: np, trying to clarify the question too from my part.

Comment: @jbx: I think, I got it: `notitlepage` is the key! I'll update

Comment: Mmm... not so sure about that one... I do want a title page (later on I will be adding my own more complex one)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Worked!!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how would change the chapter numbering from decimals to integers i.e. 0.1 to 1?