Correcting the roman page numbering after the title page
My desired page numbering style for the following MWE is like:
Title-page (blank) 
Abstract   (page ii) 
ToC        (page iii)
Chapter 1  (page 1) 

But I am getting:
Title-page (blank) 
Abstract   (page iii) 
ToC        (page iv)
Chapter 1  (page 1)

\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{
    \thispagestyle{empty}           
    \begin{center}
        \null\mbox{}\vfill
        % \includegraphics[scale=1]{university-logo.jpg}
        % \\[4ex]
        {
            \Huge \@title 
        }       
        % Extra info
        \vfill\null 
    \end{center}
} 
\makeatother

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285670/114006
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@abstractmode

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
{
  \if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
  \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \if@abstractmode
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \stepcounter{page}%
  \else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
}%
{
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
  \if@twoside\else
  \if@abstractmode
  \else
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{%
  \@abstractmodetrue%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Page Numbering}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}


Normally I'd use \frontmatter right after the title page (and have the title page use Alph (which helps with hyperef)), but it does not seem report supports \frontmatter and \mainmatter

does it help if you put a \setcounter{page}{2} just after creating the titlepage?

Why do you set \stepcounter{page} in titlepage?

@Ronald no. I just tried with \setcounter{page}{2}. It didn't work.

@jlab I am not sure about it. I took the setup from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285670/114006.
It works when I am not customizing \maketitle command.

I tried your MWE and oddly enough it works if you do a \setcounter{page}{0} just after \maketitle. If I do a \clearpage after \maketitle, the \setcounter{page}{1} gives the correct result.

Well, with the report class, \maketitle invoke titlepage. I'm not sure, but I think you should either patch titlepage either redefine \maketitle.

@Ronald I missed checking your comment. Yes, it works that way. You could post an answer! :)

Also, I like to get an explanation how it's working. :)

Just redefine abstract not to use titlepage (why is it using titlepage I don't really know).
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  % \includegraphics[scale=1]{university-logo.jpg}
  % \\[4ex]
  {\Huge \@title\par}
  % Extra info
  % ...
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \end{center}
} 
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}
}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}
\makeatother

\title{Page Numbering}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}


More easily, use book. If you want the abstract in the table of contents, use \chapter{Abstract} instead of \chapter*{Abstract}.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  % \includegraphics[scale=1]{university-logo.jpg}
  % \\[4ex]
  {\Huge \@title\par}
  % Extra info
  % ...
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \end{center}
} 
\makeatother

\title{Page Numbering}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
\blindtext[2]

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}



I am getting the desired output if I put \setcounter{page}{0} inside \renewcommand\maketitle or \renewenvironment{titlepage}:
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    \begin{center}
        \null\mbox{}\vfill
        % \includegraphics[scale=1]{university-logo.jpg}
        % \\[4ex]
        {
            \Huge \@title 
        }       
        % Extra info
        \vfill\null 
    \end{center}
} 
\makeatother

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285670/114006
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@abstractmode

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
{
  % \setcounter{page}{0}
  \if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
  \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \if@abstractmode
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \stepcounter{page}%
  \else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
}%
{
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
  \if@twoside\else
  \if@abstractmode
  \else
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{%
  \@abstractmodetrue%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Page Numbering}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}

