Starting the abstract at the odd page on twoside report
I want to set up the page layout so that the abstract, acknowledgments, ToC, chapters, etc. start at the right or odd pages for the twoside option.
Title  
Blank page       (ii)
Abstract         (iii)
Blank page       (iv)
Acknowledgments  (v)
Blank page       (vi)
Contents         (vii)
Blank page       (viii)
Introduction     (1)

For the oneside option, it should remain as:
Title  
Abstract         (ii)
Acknowledgments  (iii)
Contents         (iv)
Introduction     (1)

The PDF bookmarks should also stay accurate (screenshot from Evince, for the oneside option):

Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside, openright
]{report}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \hypersetup{
%     bookmarksnumbered=true,
% }
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{
        \setcounter{page}{0}
        \begin{center}
            {
                \Large \@title 
            }
        \end{center}
} 
\makeatother

%%% Page numbering from the abstract page % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285670/114006
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@abstractmode

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
{
  \if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
  \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \if@abstractmode
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \stepcounter{page}%
  \else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
}%
{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
  \if@twoside\else
  \if@abstractmode
  \else
  \setcounter{page}\@ne%
  \fi
  \fi
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{%
  \@abstractmodetrue%
}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pdfbookmark{Title}{title}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Abstract}{abstract}
\begin{abstract}
    Here's the abstract. \blindtext
\end{abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Acknowledgements}{acknowledgement}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}

It should be noted that the vertical alignment of the abstract should be kept the same as in this MWE.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285666/114006

I'd simply redefine abstract instead of modifying titlepage that you seem not to be using. Don't set the page counter to zero.
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside,
    openright
]{report}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{center}
  \Large\@title 
  \end{center}
} 

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries \abstractname
  \end{center}
}{\par\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Here's the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}

With the openright option you get

Title [i] (no shown page number
Blank page [ii]
Abstract [iii]
Blank page [iv]
Acknowledgments [v]
Blank page [vi]
TOC [vii]
Blank page [viii]
Introduction 1

Without openright you get

Title [i] (no shown page number)
Abstract [ii]
Acknowledgments [iii]
TOC [iv]
Introduction 1

But I believe that the best thing is to treat the abstract as an unnumbered chapter just like the Acknowledgments.
Note that I removed all explicit \cleardoublepage commands from the code inside document.
In order to fix also the bookmarks, you can do as follows:
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside,
    openright
]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{center}
  \Large\@title
  \pdfbookmark{\@title}{\@title}
  \end{center}
} 

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \safeclearpage
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \pdfbookmark{\abstractname}{\abstractname}
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries \abstractname
  \end{center}
}{\par\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage}
\newcommand{\safeclearpage}{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Here's the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\pdfbookmark{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}

\safeclearpage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents

\safeclearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}

With openright

Without openright


Thank you. I am wondering if it's generally good practice to put the page number on the blank pages, especially the one between the title page and the abstract of the dissertation.

Moreover, I just noticed, that if I don't put the explicit \cleardoublepage commands, the PDF bookmarks are not showing correct page numbers. I have updated the question details to point out the issue.

@raf Added the (small) changes.

Thanks again. However, the vertical alignment of the abstract is getting changed. Any way to keep the previous form?

@raf I see no change: the abstract is vertically centered in the page as in the standard report class. However, you should consider making it \chapter*.

Is it possible to hide the page number (i) from the title on the bookmarks as shown in my question?

Can you please recheck the vertical alignment? I just checked my MWE gives the vertically-centered alignment of the abstract as the same as the standard report class. But if you notice, with your solution, only the \abstractname is getting vertically center-aligned, not the body of the abstract. Isn't it?

@raf Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. The whole abstract is vertically centered, see picture. Of course this is as ugly as it could be.

Sorry that I was mistaken and failed to clarify. Kindly check these three screenshots: My desired output is Screenshot 1 (my MWE) or Screenshot 2. The 2nd one is obtained with \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report} \usepackage{blindtext} \begin{document} \begin{abstract} Here's the abstract. \blindtext \end{abstract} \end{document}. In contrast, using your solution, I get Screenshot 3.

@raf Add \vspace{-\topsep} after the first \vspace*{\fill}. However you should consider \chapter*{Abstract}. Have I already said it?

Thank you. It seems to give my preferred version with \vspace{-15\topsep}. Can you update in your answer too? And, for now, I like to keep the abstract style distinct from the \chapter*.

@raf You added an arbitrary amount of spacing. Now you know how to do it, that's enough.
