# latex report class \frontmatter \mainmatter and page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, abstract, report

I am using the `report` class. I want my abstract, acknowledgements and table of contents to be in the table of contents and its page number to be roman numerals. Then I want the rest after that to be in numbers. I use the code below but I have no page number on my abstract. It only shows on table of content. I dont know how to use book class because if I change the function from `report` to `book` I get a big fat error. Below code and pictures.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\linespread{1.5}   
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor=red
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 % \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
 % \@mainmatterfalse
   }

\makeatother

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{Cover_Page}

\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}    
\end{abstract}

\begingroup
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
```

[image]

[image]

i get this error when i use the code below

```
(no line number):
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Database file #1: sample.bib
Repeated entry---line 88 of file sample.bib
 : @article{videoanalysis
 :                       ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 163 of file sample.bib
 : @article{vrnn
 :              ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.14 (2015/08/26) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
Name 6 in "Jeff Donahue and Lisa Anne Hendricks and Marcus Rohrbach and Subhashini Venugopalan and Sergio Guadarrama and Kate Saenko, and Trevor Darrell" has a comma at the end for entry videoanalysis
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 2 in "Ilya Sutskever and Oriol Vinyals, and Quoc V. Le" has a comma at the end for entry machinetranslation
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Oriol Vinyals and Alexander Toshev and Samy Bengio, and Dumitru Erhan" has a comma at the end for entry imagecaptioning1
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Marco Fraccaroy and Soren Kaae Sonderbyz and Ulrich Paquet, and Ole Winther" has a comma at the end for entry srnn
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Diederik P. Kingma and Danilo J. Rezende and Shakir Mohamed, and Max Welling" has a comma at the end for entry cvae1
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 1 in "Kihyuk Sohn, Honglak Lee, and Xinchen Yan" has a comma at the end for entry cvae2
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 2 in "Nitish Srivastava and Elman Mansimov, and Ruslan Salakhutdinov" has a comma at the end for entry unsupvideo
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Serena Yeung and Anitha Kannan and Yann Dauphin, and Li Fei-Fei" has a comma at the end for entry overpruning
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 4 in "Casper Kaae Sonderby and Tapani Raiko and Lars Maaloe and Soren Kaae Sonderby, and Ole Winther" has a comma at the end for entry trainvae
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 4 in "Anirudh Goyal and Alessandro Sordoni and Marc-Alexandre Cote and Nan Rosemary Ke, and Yoshua Bengio" has a comma at the end for entry zforcing
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 5 in "Xingjian Shi and Zhourong Chen and Hao Wang and Dit-Yan Yeung and Wai-kin Wong, and Wang-chun Woo" has a comma at the end for entry convlstm
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst

Done.
You've used 23 entries,
            4087 wiz_defined-function locations,
            914 strings with 10786 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 10057 in all, are:
= -- 758
> -- 312
< -- 0
+ -- 146
- -- 73
* -- 447
:= -- 1769
add.period$ -- 46
call.type$ -- 23
change.case$ -- 23
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 23
duplicate$ -- 881
empty$ -- 906
format.name$ -- 94
if$ -- 2235
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 23
missing$ -- 165
newline$ -- 92
num.names$ -- 23
pop$ -- 469
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 2
skip$ -- 752
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 23
swap$ -- 489
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 5
type$ -- 23
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 23
width$ -- 25
write$ -- 206
(There were 13 error messages)
```

Comment: Which **big fat** error do you get with `book`? Is it complaining about the missing `abstract` environment?. Your document is incomplete

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16347/134144

Comment: `abstract` uses `titlepage`, which is using `empty` page style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `report` uses `titlepage` option or better `\@titlepagetrue` (that is set right from the beginning, so `titlepage` as option is not set explicitly) -- this has a side effect on the definition of `abstract` (code from `report.cls`,

```
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
```

Now, `\titlepage` itself uses `\thispagestyle{empty}`, so there will be no page number shown.

A patch with

```
\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\pagestyle{plain}}{}{}%
```

cures this problem.

Please note that `book.cls` does not have an abstract environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\linespread{1.5}   
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor=red
}


\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\pagestyle{plain}}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\endtitlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}% Remove the reset of page at the end of titlepage

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}
}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    % \@mainmattertrue
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
  }

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  % \@mainmatterfalse
}

\makeatother

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}

%\includepdf{Cover_Page}


\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}    
\end{abstract}

\begingroup
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps, it is better to copy over the definition of `abstract` to a file using `book` instead the other way round

Comment: I focused on the `abstract` issue ... the other issues are exercises to the O.P.

Comment: why does it page number abstract and table of contents as i ?

Comment: @kong: That's what you requested (see the beginning of your question) : `\pagenumbering{roman}`, i.e. lower case roman numbers.

Comment: sorry i meant both my abstract and table of contents are i. shouldnt my abstract be i and table of contents ii, etc

Comment: @kong: `titlepage` resets the page number at the end of the environment, so does `abstract` as well. See the update, please