# Enumerate some sections of document

Tags: page-numbering

Abstract should not be enuminated, the content list should start at I (Roman numerals) and the first chapter should start at 1 (normal numbers), how make?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}    
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
{
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
}

%\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{ABSTRACT}}%\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
El principal mecanthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis intro

\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification: your question is about the page numbers at the bottom of the page and not how the sections/chapters are numbered?

Comment: @samcarter 
yes I refer to the footnote numbers

Comment: Would switching to `\documentclass{book}` be an option for you? This has build in support for all these features

Comment: @samcarter i need report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408118/36296 you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}    
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}
}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    % \@mainmattertrue
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
  }

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  % \@mainmatterfalse
}


\begin{document}

{
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{ABSTRACT}}%\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
El principal mecanthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis intro

\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```